# Heap Corruption Error - Allocating memory

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, new-operator, fstream

I dont know what is going on -  but somehow my code is corrupting heap

```
....
unsigned char *buf[2] = {0};
buf[0] = new unsigned char(sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
buf[1] = new unsigned char(sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

if(! buf[0] || ! buf[1])
{
    std::cout << "running outta memory " << std::endl;
    return false;
}

file.read((char*)buf[0], sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
file.read((char*)buf[1], sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

m_bmpHeader = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*) buf[0];
m_bmpInfo = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*) buf[1];

if(m_bmpHeader->b_filetype[0] != 'B' || m_bmpHeader->b_filetype[1] != 'M' ||
    m_bmpInfo-> compression != 0 || m_bmpInfo-> bits_per_pixel != 24)
{
    std::cout << "Not a valid BMP file..Supporting 24 bit images only" ;
    return false;
}

m_data = new unsigned char[m_bmpInfo->imagesize];
if(! m_data)
{
    std::cout << "running outta memory " << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

heap is getting corrupted at the point `m_data = new unsigned char[m_bmpInfo->imagesize];`

If I debug the code - it stops in `fstream`; inside templated `_Fgetc` kinda saying EOF has been hit

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: `buf[0]` and `buf[1]` point to a single `char`. You probably meant `new unsigned char[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];`

Comment: You should make that an answer.

Comment: Side note -- You have a memory leak if you run out of memory at the `if (!m_data)` line.  Use `std::vector` or smart pointers instead of naked pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new unsigned char(sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
```

This does not allocate an array! It allocates a single `unsigned char`.

Write:

```
new unsigned char[sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)];
```

You get that right later on in your code, so presumably this is just a typo.